# Silverstripe 3.0 preserve tab state on save and publish

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, silverstripe

I am using Silverstripe 3.0. I have added custom tabs/sub tabs for pages...if you are on a sub tab and you publish the page, the control returns to the main tab....I need the tabs preserved...

I noticed that this has been fixed in SS 3.0.5

Can someone please point out all the related files that have been modified to fix this in SS 3.0.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking through https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/commits/3.0

Answer (score 1):

seems to be related to the 3.0.1 release(http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/changelogs/3.0.1) specifically this commit? (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/commit/155758f) but there might be more...

But you should definitely upgrade to 3.1 (http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/installation/upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you dont simply upgrade?
It should be easy by just replace the cms & framework folders.

If you would like to see the changes, i recommend to checkout or download the current version of Silverstripe 3.0 in a seperate folder, make a directory diff with your project and view the diff with a diffviewer tool like:

- Meld on Linux
- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) on Windows
- FileMerge on Mac

A full list you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).